# Не запускается анимация в сss

Tags: css, css-animation

Хочу сделать сдвиг квадрата влево, но не пойму, почему не запускается анимация... Помогите, пожалуйста

```
.b{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: rgb(88, 68, 68);
    animation: 2s face alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes face{
    from{left: 0;}
    to{left: 300px;}
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tar.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="b"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.b {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: rgb(88, 68, 68);
  animation: 2s face alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes face {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(200%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="b"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

вместо `left` используй `margin-left`

`left` изпользуется при `position: absolute , relative , fixed`
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_left.asp